# How to add an action listener for a <li> tag using its id?

Tags: javascript, html, click, html-lists

I am creating a li tag that once the user clicks it, it will post something on the console using javascript.

Here is my index.html:

```js
$('#Title').on('click', function(){
  console.log("List was clicked.");  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="Title"> List 1 </li>
<li id="Title"> List 2 </li>
<li id="Title"> List 3 </li>
```

But it doesn't do anything, are there any approach to this?

Comment: You can't have multiple tags that have the same ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you are using the same `id` attribute for each item in the list. It has to be unique in the document. You can use a class if you want to give the same name. See Example below:

HTML:

```
<li class="Title">List 1</li>
<li class="Title">List 2</li>
<li class="Title">List 3</li>
```

JS:

```
$('.Title').on('click', function(){
    console.log("List was clicked.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple tags that have a same ID

```js
$('#Title2').on('click', function(){
    console.log("List 2 was clicked.")  });
```

```html
<li id="Title1"> List 1 </li>
<li id="Title2"> List 2 </li>
<li id="Title3"> List 3 </li>
```